# SSRS 2008 R2 - When a Field used as Column Group has a NULL value, values not populating in column

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportbuilder3.0

A user has created a simple matrix report created in Report Builder 3.0 SSRS 2008 R2.  There is one column grouping based on Posting Dates.  There is a dataset for Posting Dates which pulls all posting dates.
There are two parameters set up as well:
Here's part of the dataset query that creates and passes the dates to the parameters.
    WHERE

```
  (LoanMaster.PostingDate = @PostingDate
  OR LoanMaster.PostingDate = @PostingDate2)
```

Normally, this works fine and displays like this:

```
8/1/2014 | 8/7/2014
-------------------
$3,300.00| 3,523.00
```

However, on July 4, no posting occurred.  Now the values for the days before the 7/4 posting date do not display in the report. The report displays as:

```
7/1/2014 | 7/7/2014
-------------------
         | 3,523.00
```

I've verified that there is data for the 7/1/2014 date. Just unsure of why the data won't display for this date range.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. Based on the WHERE, it is only getting 2 dates and not the range within the 2 dates. If you want the range you would need to use (LoanMaster.PostingDate >= @postingDate AND LoanMaster.PostingDate <= @PostingDate2)

Comment: Actually, not needing the range.  We are just wanting the two dates.

Comment: Is it possible for you to post some dummy data with dates to understand better

Answer (score 0):

This type of weird result is often due to the null values in the column. Try using the ISNULL function in your dataset:

```
ISNULL(VALUE,'')
```